# How do I open the DevTools in google Chrome using Selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is this even possible I saw one other post about this topic and its solution was to use pyautogui but I can't do that because I need the keys to only register for the chromedriver.

I have tried the typical

> driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"body").send_keys(Keys.F12)

but to no avail I had also tried

> driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + "i")

and this also did not work as well.

Comment: Why would you need that??

Answer (score 0):

There are some other workarounds depending on what your goal is.

If you need to open devtools to handle requests I would recommend using [Selenium Wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)